# How to set my own x axis labels for a time series plot in R?

Tags: r, plot, time-series, axis-labels

I have a time series and when I plot it, the default x-axis is not well labeled.

```
aa=sample(x=1:500,size = 804,replace = T)
Year_mon <- seq(from=as.Date("1950-01-15"),to=as.Date("2016-12-15"),by="months")
plot(aa~Year_mon, type="l", lty=1)
```

[image]

What I want is to show 1950, 1960, 1970,..., 2010 as the x axis label. I have tried the following codes, but failed. Is there any suggestion? Thanks a lot.

```
plot(aa~Year_mon, type="l", lty=1,xaxt="n")
ix <- seq(1, 721, by=120)
axis(side=1, at=ix, labels=seq(1950,2010,by=10))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `axis.Date` to achieve this.

```
set.seed(1234)
aa <- sample(x=1:500,size = 804, replace = T)
Year_mon <- seq(from = as.Date("1950-01-15"), to = as.Date("2016-12-15"), by = "months")
plot(aa~Year_mon, type = "l", lty = 1)
axis.Date(1, at = as.Date(paste0(seq(1950, 2010, 10), "-01-01")), format="%Y")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. But could you explain a bit why my codes do not work? Thanks.

Comment: `Year_mon` is date, so you need `axis.Date`.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: Take a look at `?Dates`. It says "Dates are represented as the number of days since 1970-01-01, with negative values for earlier dates."  So when you placed one label at 1, that was for 1970-01-02. And then you stepped up by 10 days at a time.

Comment: @G5W Thank you so much for your further explanation.